# Spring: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I've having a tough time getting a basic jsp file to render in my browser.  I had it working fine, but then I tried to make a header.jsp and a footer.jsp file to include in my student.jsp file.  When I abstracted this out is when I began to have issues.

I am very new to Spring MVC, so patience is appreciated :)

The error I get when I go to: localhost:8080/myprojectStudentCourses/student

From the console is:

> Dec 06, 2014 12:52:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound
>   noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/myprojectStudentCourses/WEB-INF/jsp/student.jsp] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'myprojectStudentCourses'

**myproject-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>myproject Student Courses</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myprojectStudentCourses</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myprojectStudentCourses</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myprojectStudentCourses</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**student.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@include file="header.jsp" %>
<form:form method="POST" action="/myprojectStudentCourses/addStudent">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
<%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

**Controller**

```
package com.myproject;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView student() {
      return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, 
   ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
      model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
      model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

      return "result";
   }
}
```

Comment: remove your url mapping entry with *.jsp in your web.xml

Comment: Yeah, you already map /* so all the file name will be going to dispatcher. So you do not need *.jsp

Comment: Ah!  You guys are awesome...I also had to change the /* to just a /

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Angad and zawhtut, I changed my web.xml to the following and it works!

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>myproject Student Courses</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myprojectStudentCourses</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myprojectStudentCourses</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```